# Link in table of contents , table of figures

Tags: links

I am using KOMA-scripts in Lyx for my project now. I would like to show a link in the table of content, table of figures... as below:

**1. Introduction**.................. 1
**2. Chapter 1**......................2

At the moment the link is in Introduction, Chapter 1......I would like to link to pages only **1, 2**...... How to show the link to pages not the text in the table of content please?
Thanks!

Comment: `\usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref}` is what you want, most probably,alternatively use `\hypersetup{linktocpage=true}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer '\hypersetup{linktocpage=true}' work for me. Thanks!